# PTIJ: Bal Tashchis and the Recycle Bin

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Is it considered Bal Tashchis to delete files/folders needlessly on a computer, or to send data to [/dev/null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device) in Linux?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 10):

If your filesystem database has a linked list tree structure then this is *baal tashchis*, as the files are the fruits of a tree.

There are some *poskim* who rule that the entire Windows OS is *ba'al tashchis meikara* which invalidates part of your question, however.

Comment: Also a doubly linked list!

Comment: +1 for bashing windows!

Comment: @chessprogrammer Everyone has to pay their Micro$oft tax

Answer (score 3):

It is only bal tashchis if you delete [cookies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)

Answer (score 1):

Only if the file has hebrew letters in it.

Comment: Seeing as you're not allowed to cut down non-Jewish trees, you're probably not allowed to cut down non-Jewish files either